# Need some help on Wordpress issue

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities, wordpress

When I am accessing my Wordpress website, for example:

`https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=revslider_show_image&img=../wp-config.php`

it's returning a page containing zero.

Is this a vulnerability? Can someone help on this issue? If this is a vulnerability, how to protect against it?

I am getting lot of logs for particular website."example.com/wp-admin/…; i dont know what the intented output but when i tried accessing the url i got "0".

Comment: Containing zero what? Zero bytes? I wouldn't suggest this is a vulnerability but a plug-in bug.

Comment: You also don't tell us what the expected result is, or if there is anything unusual with the HTTP request. Please edit your question to add more context.

Comment: @schroeder iam getting message like  this "0".

Comment: @schroeder I am getting lot of logs for particular website."https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=revslider_show_image&img=../wp-config.php" i dont know what the intented output but when i tried accessing the url i got "0"...

Comment: ok - hold on - the URL request is one you found in the logs, and it is unexpected? You need to include these things in your question! It looks like someone is trying to access your wp-config.php file by using the image slider plug-in. Update your plug-ins to make sure any vulnerabilities are patched, or change to plug-ins that do not have published vulnerabilities.

Comment: @schroeder : The message "0" corresponds to the vulnerability present in the plugin?

Comment: no - I do not know if there is a vulnerability, but the attacker is trying to exploit one, if there is one.

Comment: I posted an answer. I am just curious if you are even running the Slider Revolution plugin at all. admin-ajax.php will exist on a WP install but it is likely returning "0" because Slider Revolution is not an installed plugin. And they are just randomly testing the exploit against you hoping for opportunity.

Comment: @schroeder @ Brad Metcalf thanks for your post!!!1

Answer (score 2):

Since you never know, when new vulnerability will be found, my suggestion for you is to install mod_security on server side.

It's not 100% security, but at least, it will make harder for hacker to perform attacks such as LFI, RFI etc.

Answer (score 1):

The URL in question is part of a [Local File Inclusion attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability) targeting the [Slider Revolution plugin](https://blog.sucuri.net/2014/09/slider-revolution-plugin-critical-vulnerability-being-exploited.html). The objective of this particular attack is to make the wp-config.php downloadable in a raw, non processed format. Doing so would give the attacker your database credentials as well as any other stored credentials such as FTP and mail server login information. Since your server is returning a "0" and not a download stream or echo of your configuration it appears you are using a patched version of this plugin.

Edit: It is also possible you don't even have this plugin installed at all. As the file it is requesting exists on every WP install. But the request it is making would return false if you do not have this plugin installed.